# DB ACCESS form keeps adding a new record vs displaying the latest record from table

Tags: sql, ms-access

There is a form recordsource to a table named `Dynamic`.
Using two textboxes to query the table: `search_SO` and `Search_Item`. (There are about 30 or so fields I just shortened it to simplify).

added Specifics:
-Bound form with all the table fields
-Search_SO & Search_Item are unbound, and search button all 3 located on the same form
-at the bottom added a subform1

Issues I need assistance with:

1. When I press the search button I get a record loaded into the main form; however, instead of displaying the latest record etc. from the table, **it keeps creating a new record on every press**.
2. When I load the recordsource to my subform it displays only one record instead of all the records available - IDK why?
   *I am at my limit and would like to ask for assistance please.*
   code:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Dynamic WHERE Sal_Order = " & Me.search_SO & " AND Item = " & Me.Search_Item & " ORDER BY ID DESC"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If Not rs.EOF Then

'Me.ID = rs!ID
Me.Date = rs!Date
Me.Sal_Order = rs!Sal_Order
Me.Item = rs!Item
Me.Customer = rs!Customer

Else
Me.Undo
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

'add the recordsource to the subform

Dim newRS As String

newRS = "SELECT * FROM Dynamic WHERE Sal_Order = " & Me.search_SO & " AND Item = " & Me.Search_Item & " ORDER BY ID DESC"
Me!Subform1.Form.RecordSource = newRS
Me!Subform1.Form.Requery
Me!Subform1.Form.Refresh
```

Comment: You might have only one item satisfying your search criterion?

Comment: Controls used to enter search criteria should be UNBOUND, otherwise you edit data or create new record. What data types are Sal_Order and Item? If controls are bound to fields, why are you setting their values via code? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: /@June7 search_SO Plain Text unbound on the form, Large Number on table, 
Search_Item Plain Text unbound on the form, Number on table. I need to search by both of these items in order to get all the records for that specific item, as Sal_Order has multiple different Item numbers. appreciate your help